# Vue/Vuex - How to retrieve data from grandchildren

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

started with VueJs for the first time
 yesterday and now I'm stuck..

I have a parent component who has child items that also has a child inside them (I call them grandchildren). I want to fetch data from all the grandchildren when i click a button in the parent but i can't figure out how.

In my mind a want to call an event from parent to to all the grandchildrens that they should store their data to vuex store. Is this possible somehow or is there another way to do this?

```
// Data
blocks = [
    {
        id: 1,
        type: 'HeadingBlock',
        title: 'Hello',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        type: 'ImageBlock',
        image_id: 2
    }
];


// App.js

<ContentBlocks :blocks="blocks" / >

// ContentBlock.vue

<ContentBlockItem v-for="(block, index) in blocks" :component="block.type" ... />

// ContentBlockItem.vue

<component :is="component" :block="block" /> // Grandchild

// component aka the grandchild (eg. HeadingBlock.vue)

data() {
  return {
    title: 'Hello - I want save the changed data for this heading',
    color: 'blue'
  }
}
```

So, the only call to action happens in the parent by a "save"-button. And i want as little logic in grandchildren as possible (to make it easy to create new ones, like a "ParagraphBlock").

Thx in advance

Comment: Well, In this case, you can call an action to store and do your task and share the state with all the component(Parent + child + grand child).

Comment: I suggest you read up on vuex. Vuex was specifically designed for solving problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to `emit()` a global `Event` that all your components subscribe to - however it seems rather impractical. (e.g. `this.$root.emit('saveData')` in parent; in all children to listen to it: `this.$root.on('saveData')`)

A more practical approach is to store all your component data in the `store` in the first place. And have each component retrieve its state from the store. (e.g. in a computed property: `title() { return this.$store.myComponent.title }`.

The trick here is obviously to set all your store-data correctly (e.g. with componentIDs to match it correctly). To do this you need to be aware, that vuex does not support `maps` or `sets`. Also, you have to set each property/element individually - you cannot set nested structures in one go bu thave to do it recursively. Hereby `Arrays` have to be filled with native array methods (`push(), splice()`) and `Object` properties have to be set with `Vue.set(object, key, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing data between parent and child component you can use one of the best features of vue is vuex store. It's really helpful when you want to pass data to child component and update that data in child and again pass back to parent without the use of props and event emit.

Here is a link you can follow for your web application

https://medium.com/dailyjs/mastering-vuex-zero-to-hero-e0ca1f421d45

https://medium.com/vue-mastery/vuex-explained-visually-f17c8c76d6c4

I hope this will help you.